# MVC action to response to jQuery Ajax requests, do I set doc type in header?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My .net MVC action is going to respond to ajax requests (jquery).

Do I (or should I) set the document type of my header?

I will be responding with either just html/plain text or maybe even JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's responding with html/plain text use:

```
Content-Type: text/html;
```

If it's responding with JSON use:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

It is good practice to do so, although it really depends on what you're doing with the responded data.

Sometimes JavaScript frameworks will automatically *work* the response depending on the Header. For example PrototypeJs automatically `sanitizes` and `eval`s the response if it has "`application/json`" header.

Answer (score 1):

If you return View() or Json(), as usual, then this is already done for you. No action required on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about MVC actions, but in .NET 3.5, you'd usually use a WPF service (.svc) to respond to a request, and it responds using JSON by default.

It can also accept JSON input using the `WebInvoke` annotation's `RequestFormat` property.